# I am getting an Error (-32300): transport error - HTTP status code was not 200

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I am getting an Error when I try to upload data using xmlrpc in wordpress. The code used to work fine but all of a sudden this error started appearing. I have not changed anything in the code.

Error (-32300): transport error - HTTP status code was not 200

Also, I know my script works because google chrome returns an 'ok' status on the GET request.
php.ini has 128mb of memory allocated.

Here is the code that is used to make post

```
    /**
     * Make Posts using the XMLRPC classes
     */
    function makePosts() {
        $data_set = $this->getMovieLinks();

        $xml_client = new XMLRPClientWordPress();

        foreach ($data_set as $key) {
            echo '<pre>';
            echo 'This is title movie about to be added ========   : ' . $key['title'];    
            echo '</pre>';

            //new_post($title,$summary,$category,$image_url,$internal_links)
        if ($xml_client->new_post($key['title'], $key['summary'], $key['category'], $key['image'], $key['internal_links']) ) {
            $status=1;
        } else {
        $status=0;
        }

            if (isset($status)) {
                echo '     ======    ADDED';  
            } else {
                echo '     ======    ERROR ADDING';  
            }
        }
    } // Function makePosts endes here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do few things to debug the error.

1. Take a look in the server logs, maybe they include the real reason for the problem.
2. Look for "memory_limit" in your php.ini. Try higher number and see whether that's the problem.
3. Try deactivating one plugin at a time, May be one plugin may causing the error.

Comment: I did deactivate all the plugins but I still get the same error. I am using shared hosting so logs are not that helpful. how much should I increase the memory limit by. So far the people with memory limit problems had their memory set up to 10mb that is default I have it to 128mb

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error, finally I found out the reason was I that I enabled such code in `.htaccess` (XML-PRC server side); I was blocked myself.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 211.111.0.0/16
```

The server hosted "http://example.com/xmlrpc.php" was blocked post script IP source.

You should:

1. Add the XML-RPC client script IP to XML-PRC server side; even the client and server in same site.
2. Or simply remove "deny from all" from `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error but i solved it :

I typed http://www.example.com/xmlrpc.php but the good is http://example.com/xmlrpc.php because if it have "www" prefix it redirected with staus cod

Comment: All HTTP responses have a status code.  Did you mean a particular status code?

Comment: Yes, it redirected with 303. :)

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above solutions work:

Make sure you are not being white-listed on the hosting provider. Our client uses wp-engine and we had this exact issue when posting media items.

After making the same request on an outside network, different IP, we got a 200 (OK) status code.